# Why did the aliens wait until the Robinsons were into the orbit to get their energy source?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost-in-space-2018

In the Netflix series *Lost in Space*, we see that the Robot is damaged and its ship has fallen into the planet with the rest of the Jupiter spacecraft.

In the final episode we see that something gets stuck beneath the chariot of the Robinson's and once they are into the orbit the Alien ship comes looking for it.

If they were looking for that thing the whole time, then why didn't they just land on the planet and take it back. Why did the aliens wait until Robinson's Jupiter spacecraft was into the orbit and then they attacked ?

Comment: I don't have anything but conjecture, so I won't jump straight to putting this as an answer, but here's my best guess: We don't have enough information.  The alien ship may not have arrived until just that moment, or maybe it wasn't able to detect the engine until it was in use and outside the planet's atmosphere again.  Maybe something about the planet itself discouraged them.  We just don't have enough information about their values, motivations, and capabilities to make a solid guess.